# Robust Standard Errors Similar to Normal Standard Errors

Tags: regression, stata

I have a question:
if robust standard errors are similar to the normal standard errors and not all of them are larger, can we then conclude that the dataset is very homoskedastic?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what "not all of them are larger" might mean?  What exactly are you comparing to what??  Perhaps you could offer an illustration that reflects the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** Probably not

**Long answer:**

If you have heteroskedasticity, but the variance of your errors is independent of the included covariates, robust standard errors will be very similar to OLS standard errors. They won't be as close compared to having homoskedastic errors.

If the variance of your error terms is higher when included covariates are far from their means, OLS standard errors will tend to be biased down, and robust standard errors will tend to be larger than OLS standard errors. This is usually what you see in practice.

When the variance of the error terms is lower when included covariates are far from their means, OLS standard errors will tend to be too large, and robust standard errors will tend to be smaller than OLS standard errors. This is pretty exotic in my personal experience. I am not sure if I have ever seen this in a real-world dataset.

Here is Stata output demonstrating the above using regressions on simulated data:

```
. clear

. /* (1) Generate Fake Data */
. set obs 10000
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 10,000.

. set seed 1052021

. generate x =  rnormal(100,15)

. // This looks cryptic, but I just played around with
. // the transformations until 
. // all three errors were mean zero
. // and the errors had the same variance
. generate e0 = rnormal(0,301) -  2.469

. generate e1 = rnormal(0, (sin(x)+1)*243) + 0.437

. generate e2 = rnormal(0, x^2)/35.75 + 4.81

. generate e3 = rnormal(0, 5e3*normalden(x,100,15))*2.95 - 0.31

. generate y0 = 10 + 5*x + e0

. generate y1 = 10 + 5*x + e1

. generate y2 = 10 + 5*x + e2

. generate y3 = 10 + 5*x + e3

. // Plot the Data
. twoway (scatter y0 x), name(y0, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))

. twoway (scatter y1 x), name(y1, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))

. twoway (scatter y2 x), name(y2, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))

. twoway (scatter y3 x), name(y3, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))

. graph combine y0 y1 y2 y3, xcommon

. summarize e*

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
          e0 |     10,000    .0004878    300.5657  -1251.636   1336.435
          e1 |     10,000    .0000975    300.0096   -1626.21   1784.588
          e2 |     10,000    .0037573    300.2937  -1446.295   1615.782
          e3 |     10,000    .0007922    300.2773  -1873.059   1364.058

. /* (2) Fit OLS With Ordinary and Het-Robust SEs */
. regress y0 x

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 9998)      =    634.22
       Model |  57301350.9         1  57301350.9   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   903307230     9,998  90348.7927   R-squared       =    0.0597
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0596
       Total |   960608581     9,999  96070.4651   Root MSE        =    300.58

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y0 | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.999955   .1985386    25.18   0.000      4.61078    5.389131
       _cons |   10.00496   20.05918     0.50   0.618    -29.31507    49.32499
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y0 x, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                F(1, 9998)        =     639.68
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.0597
                                                Root MSE          =     300.58

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
          y0 | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.999955     .19769    25.29   0.000     4.612443    5.387467
       _cons |   10.00496   20.00716     0.50   0.617     -29.2131    49.22302
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y1 x

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 9998)      =    600.94
       Model |  54090825.6         1  54090825.6   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   899921160     9,998   90010.118   R-squared       =    0.0567
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0566
       Total |   954011985     9,999  95410.7396   Root MSE        =    300.02

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y1 | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.857866   .1981661    24.51   0.000      4.46942    5.246311
       _cons |   24.19839   20.02155     1.21   0.227    -15.04787    63.44466
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y1 x, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                F(1, 9998)        =     641.91
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.0567
                                                Root MSE          =     300.02

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
          y1 | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.857866   .1917376    25.34   0.000     4.482021     5.23371
       _cons |   24.19839   19.42984     1.25   0.213      -13.888    62.28479
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y2 x

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 9998)      =    565.06
       Model |    50949701         1    50949701   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   901486350     9,998  90166.6683   R-squared       =    0.0535
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0534
       Total |   952436051     9,999  95253.1304   Root MSE        =    300.28

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y2 | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.714705   .1983384    23.77   0.000     4.325922    5.103488
       _cons |   38.50287   20.03895     1.92   0.055    -.7775081    77.78325
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y2 x, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                F(1, 9998)        =     457.00
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.0535
                                                Root MSE          =     300.28

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
          y2 | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   4.714705   .2205436    21.38   0.000     4.282395    5.147015
       _cons |   38.50287   20.65658     1.86   0.062    -1.988177    78.99392
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y3 x

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 9998)      =    661.37
       Model |  59637456.8         1  59637456.8   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   901550824     9,998   90173.117   R-squared       =    0.0620
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0620
       Total |   961188281     9,999  96128.4409   Root MSE        =    300.29

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y3 | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   5.100858   .1983454    25.72   0.000     4.712061    5.489655
       _cons |  -.0742689   20.03967    -0.00   0.997    -39.35605    39.20751
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress y3 x, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                F(1, 9998)        =    2024.13
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.0620
                                                Root MSE          =     300.29

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
          y3 | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   5.100858   .1133769    44.99   0.000     4.878617      5.3231
       _cons |  -.0742689   11.75118    -0.01   0.995    -23.10895    22.96041
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's a graph of the data:

[image]

y0 is homoskedastic and the ratio of vanilla to robust SE for $x$ is $\frac{.1985386}{.19769} = 1.00$.

y1 is heteroskedastic, but not in a way that depends on $x$ monotonically. Here the error variance is sinusoidal in $x$. Here the ratio is $\frac{.1981661}{.1917376}=1.03$. This is still pretty close to 1.

y2 is the usual case, where the variance increases with $x$. Now the ratio is $\frac{.1983384}{.2205436} = .90$, so the robust errors are 10% larger.

y3 is the exotic one, where the error variance is lower at the tails of $x$. here the ratio is $\frac{.1983454}{.1133769} = 1.74$, so OLS is a lot bigger.

**This is all to say if your errors are similar, you cannot distinguish between a situation where your errors are homoskedastic or heteroskedastic.** The y0 vs y1 regressions show this.

Robust SEs also have small-sample bias and higher sampling variance. Stata implements a correction for the first that works reasonably well in moderate samples, like we have here. But you could still get the robust ones to be too small by chance alone because of the second. This gets more complicated as you add many covariates which may be correlated with each other and have different types of heteroskedasticity.

The second lesson here is that it's not helpful to use differences between SEs to diagnose homoskedasticity. There are better tools for that (residual-versus-fitted plot, residual-versus-predictor plot, Breusch–Pagan and Cook–Weisberg tests for heteroskedasticity or various information matrix tests).

In practice, [some books](https://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/) suggest using whichever SEs are biggest to be conservative (and also using various types of robust errors, HCx). This is advice that performs fairly well in simulation.

---

**Stata Code:**

```
cls
clear
/* (1) Generate Fake Data */
set obs 10000
set seed 1052021
generate x =  rnormal(100,15)
// This looks cryptic, but I just played around with
// the transformations until 
// all three errors were mean zero
// and the errors had the same variance
generate e0 = rnormal(0,301) -  2.469
generate e1 = rnormal(0, (sin(x)+1)*243) + 0.437
generate e2 = rnormal(0, x^2)/35.75 + 4.81
generate e3 = rnormal(0, 5e3*normalden(x,100,15))*2.95 - 0.31
generate y0 = 10 + 5*x + e0
generate y1 = 10 + 5*x + e1
generate y2 = 10 + 5*x + e2
generate y3 = 10 + 5*x + e3
// Plot the Data
twoway (scatter y0 x), name(y0, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))
twoway (scatter y1 x), name(y1, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))
twoway (scatter y2 x), name(y2, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))
twoway (scatter y3 x), name(y3, replace) ytitle(, orientation(horizontal))
graph combine y0 y1 y2 y3, xcommon
summarize e*
/* (2) Fit OLS With Ordinary and Het-Robust SEs */
regress y0 x
regress y0 x, vce(robust)
regress y1 x
regress y1 x, vce(robust)
regress y2 x
regress y2 x, vce(robust)
regress y3 x
regress y3 x, vce(robust)
```

Comment: For the exotic case, is this obvious a priori? Naively I would have expected this to have larger robust standard errors, thus is there an intuitive way of understanding why it is the OLS that is bigger?

Comment: @SingleMalt Observations of $x$ far from the mean are both less dispersed around the regression line and contain more information. So when you allow the variance to vary across observations, robust errors take advantage of that and the precision of coefficients really improves.

Comment: So is the robust SE for this case accurate or downward biased? If the latter then your examples show the reasoning behind using the maximum of the OLS and robust SEs.

Comment: It's "accurate" since there is heteroskedasticity, in the sense of giving you the specified type I error rate.

Comment: @AdelMoin Did this clear things up?