# Why how to check heteroscedasticity of residuals in linear regression

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Before asking the particular question, I want to know ***why*** is heteroscedasticity a matter of concern?

***How to portray it?*** Intuitively, I think it is plot of actual values of DV vs the residuals. This is what I thus begot

[image]

If my intuition is correct and so is the graph, what inference could I draw from it? Are the residuals heteroscedastic? If yes, ***how much?*** What is the ***acceptable limit?***

Comment: Some of your questions are answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559284/robust-standard-errors-similar-to-normal-standard-errors/559492#559492). Scroll down to the graph and the discussion below.

Comment: Consider plotting (studentized) residuals vs. regressors, too. This is by the definition of heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Thank you, I'll refer to the suggestions of both of you

Comment: By the way, does it even matter to have homoscedastic residuals when my goal is to make predictions?